# Confusing date comparing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm confused about this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [content count]; i++) {
    NSString *dateString = [self replaceCharacters:[[[content objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
    NSLog(@"\n\n%i",[[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[originalDate dateFromString:[[[content objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"] objectForKey:@"text"]]] intValue]);
    if ([[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[originalDate dateFromString:dateString]] intValue] >= [todayString intValue]) {
        [tempContent addObject:[content objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

}
```

I'll explain:

I need to check if the date of every object in contents is higher or equal to the today date. If it's so, it will be added to the tempContent. But the tempContent count is equal to the content count. Nothing got sorted...

Does anyone see the solution?!

Thanks,
mavrick3.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to add the dates that are in the future to tempContent? Are you including the time in the comparison, or only the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `NSDate`s `-compare:` method? It returns you the constant `NSOrderedDescending`, if the first date is later in time, `NSOrderedAscending` if it is earlier and you will find out yourself when it returns `NSOrderedSame`.

For example:

```
if ([originalDate compare:todayDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        [tempContent addObject:[content objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: I used this `if ([[originalDate dateFromString:dateString] compare:today] == (NSOrderedDescending || NSOrderedSame)) {
    
    [tempContent addObject:[content objectAtIndex:i]];
   }` but it doesn't work for dates which are equal to today date...

Comment: `||` is the bitwise or operator. If you write it that way, you apply it to the constants, not to the comparison results. Try `if ([[originalDate dateFromString:dateString] compare:today] == NSOrderedDescending || [[originalDate dateFromString:dateString] compare:today] == NSOrderedSame) { [tempContent addObject:[content objectAtIndex:i]]; }`

Comment: I tried to remember it this way: if you have `[A compare:B]`, try to imagine that it's a sequence of two integers `A B` read from left to right. If `A = 5` and `B = 3`, then the sequence is `5 3`; therefore, the sequence is called **descending** (`NSOrderedDescending`).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use NSDateComponents, instead of all of that stringFromDate stuff.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854890/comparing-two-nsdates-and-ignoring-the-time-component) for more info.

But basically you will want something like:

```
unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* origComponents = [calendar components:flags fromDate:originalDate];
NSDate* origDateOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:origComponents];

for (int i = 0; i < [content count]; i++) 
{
    NSDate *date = [[content objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date];
    NSDate* dateOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    if ([origDateOnly compare:dateOnly] == (NSOrderedSame || NSOrderedAscending)) 
    {
         [tempContent addObject:[content objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this I get some errors... I know that I need to add some stuff... But the whole code is buggy...

Comment: I fixed one bug I found in my code but since you didn't provide much info in your original code (like the structure of your "content" object), I just typed something up quick in the browser and didn't really test it. The main idea is using the date components instead of a date->string->int conversion to compare is much cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Erica Sadun's NSDate-Extensions. It has lots of useful methods like `isEqualToDateIgnoringTime:` and `isLaterThanDate:`

This helped me solving problems similar to yours.