# Converting NSStrings in an array into NSDates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm working on an assignment that allows the user to display events that are happening 'today'. I have parsed the XML file and stored the contents into an array. The contents of the XML file consists of a title, description, date etc. The dates are in NSString format and I want to convert them into NSDates and compare them with today's date before displaying them in a UITableView.

I'm new to obj-c and I've searched online for help on NSDate, but I couldn't find what I need. Any links, advice or help on this is really appreciated. Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose dateString contains the date in string format

first get date from string:-

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
  NSDate *dateprevious = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Now get today date

```
    NSDate *date=[NSDate date]; 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    NSString *dateOfGame =[formatter stringFromDate:dateprevious];
    NSString *todaydate =[formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];

if([todaydate isEqualToString:dateknown])
{
NSLog(@"date matched");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy , hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSDate *date = [[dateFormatter datefromString:date] retain];
[dateFormatter release];
```

You can use this one

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the format of the string, you can use [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
+ (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string
```

To compare two dates you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854890/comparing-two-nsdates-and-ignoring-the-time-component) a lot of usefull answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**NSDateFormatter**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It has a method called dateFromString
Like you could do the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"5/5/2011"];
```