# date in a specific range with NSOrderedAscending and NSOrderedDescending

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have this code:

```
NSComparisonResult compareStart = [firstDate compare: dateSelected]; 
NSComparisonResult compareEnd = [secondDate compare: dateSelected];

if (((compareStart == NSOrderedAscending) || (compareStart == NSOrderedSame))
                   && (compareEnd == NSOrderedDescending))
```

but it don't entry in the "if" when firstDate = dateSelected or secondDate = dateSelected...why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that when firstDate equals dateSelected that date selected is earlier than secondDate?  Currently your logic is: firstDate <= dateSelected < secondDate.  If you want firstDate <= dateSelected <= secondDate, then you need to implement the code as follows:

```
NSComparisonResult compareStart = [firstDate compare: dateSelected]; 
NSComparisonResult compareEnd = [secondDate compare: dateSelected];

if ( (compareStart == NSOrderedAscending || compareStart == NSOrderedSame)
                   && (compareEnd == NSOrderedDescending || compareEnd == NSOrderedSame)) {
  // some code
}
```

**Update:**

To compare two NSDates without relying on time see: [Comparing two NSDates and ignoring the time component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854890/comparing-two-nsdates-and-ignoring-the-time-component)

Comment: you code entry in the "if" only when firstDate < dataSelected < secondDate; but I want that my code entry in the if when firstDate <= dataSelected <= secondDate

Comment: There must be some confusion.  The code I supplied is: firstDate <= dateSelected <= secondDate

Comment: 2011-06-06 12:59:48.994 Project[419:707] firstDate:2011-06-06 10:59:21 +0000
2011-06-06 12:59:49.001 Project[419:707] secondDate:2011-06-09 00:00:00 +0000
2011-06-06 12:59:49.004 Project[419:707] selectedData:2011-06-06 10:59:17 +0000

Comment: selectedDate is 4 seconds before firstDate.  That's why it's not working.

Comment: I"m sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I've posted a link in the main post under "update" with the information you need.