# Loop between two NSDates in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have two dates StartDate and EndDate. I want to find specific days e.g. Monday between these two dates.

How can I execute a loop between two dates?

Comment: I don't see how he's asking for code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are really two parts to this question:

- how turn a date into a monday
- how to loop between dates adding a week every time.

## Making a date into a monday

You can use `NSCalendar` to get a monday. In the code below I use the current calendar and change the first day of the week to monday and then make the date the "beginning of the week". It's a trick that I picked up from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857392/608157).

```
NSDate *loopDate = // the start date you are looping from
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
currentCalendar.firstWeekday = 2; // Monday
[currentCalendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&loopDate interval:NULL forDate:loopDate];
```

when I run it right now (my loop date is 3 months ago) it changes `Friday, May 17, 2013 at 5:57:26 PM GMT+2` into `Monday, May 13, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2` (which is the monday before that).

## Looping by adding one week

This is really simple. Create date components for "one week" and add it to the date as long as it's smaller than the end date.

```
NSDateComponents *oneWeek = [NSDateComponents new];
oneWeek.week = 1;

while ([loopDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    loopDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:oneWeek toDate:loopDate options:0];
    // Do something with the date
}
```

When I ran this code and logged the dates I got:

```
Monday, May 20, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, May 27, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, June 3, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, June 10, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, June 17, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, June 24, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, July 1, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, July 8, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, July 15, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, July 22, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, July 29, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, August 5, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, August 12, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
Monday, August 19, 2013 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to add periods of time to a date. You can then loop and repeatedly add the period until `compare:` indicates that you have passed the end date.