# Possible to compare NSDate objects without using calendar components?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm looking to compare `NSDate` objects based on the day only (ignoring time). Instead of converting the time to 0:00:00, or using `NSDateComponent` like most solutions (ex. [Comparing two NSDates and ignoring the time component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854890/comparing-two-nsdates-and-ignoring-the-time-component))

Does anyone see an issue with converting the date to an `int` representing the number of days since 1970 with the `timeIntervalSince1970` method?

```
return (int)([date timeIntervalSince1970]/(SECONDS_PER_DAY));
```

Comment: Calendrical calculations are very error-prone. I suggest watching the "Performing Calendar Calculations" keynote presentation from WWDC 2011 on why it is not recommended you do these calculations on your own.

Comment: There are ways to do this, but they are subject to timezone and DST-caused glitches.  Depends on how precise you want to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. There are an endless number of pitfalls with date math. Use NSDateComponents; they’re not hard.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *date1Components = [cal components:NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];
NSDateComponents *date2Components = [cal components:NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date2];
NSComparisonResult comparison = [[cal dateFromComponents:date1Components] compare:[cal dateFromComponents:date2Components];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to convert an `NSDate` to an `NSTimeInterval` that represents midnight of the original date without using `NSCalendar`. Doing this with two `NSDate` objects would let you compare the two dates without regard to time.

```
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // Your original date with time
    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSince1970]; // the full interval
    NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [form setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]]; // Zulu time
    [form setDateFormat:@"A"]; // milliseconds since midnight
    NSString *secondsStr = [form stringFromDate:now];
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [secondsStr integerValue] / 1000.0; // seconds since midnight
    NSTimeInterval justDate = interval - seconds; // interval for date at midnight (Zulu time)

    // For testing purposes
    NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:justDate];
    NSLog(@"now = %@, interval = %f", now, interval);
    NSLog(@"seconds = %@", secondsStr);
    NSLog(@"justDate = %f, nowDate = %@", justDate, nowDate);
```

This may or may not be better than using `NSCalendar` as shown in Noah's answer.

You must definitely not simply divide by `SECONDS_PER_DAY`. That will simply be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(date1, toDate: date2, toUnitGranularity: .Day)
```

Returns `NSComparisonResult`

[Here is what apple talks about it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTAZ3.png)

Comment: while writing the answer, better if you can explain the code snippet!

Comment: Read here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:

Comment: you should update your answer with relevant info from that link to make it more helpful