# Objective C how to compare two date_time with the ignorance on second value

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

Actually we want to compare the NSDate in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", so how can we compare two date_time value for the date, hour and minute and ignore the second value in the objective c, ios ?

Comment: set the second values to `00` at both dates, and they won't mess the comparison up.

Comment: You could use a `NSDateFormatter` to transforms those two `NSString` objects into `NSDate` objects, and then use `NSDateComponents` to check equality on the components that are relevant. Or, if they have really the same and easy format as you set (same timezone, etc.) you can just do a comparison on the substring (removing the last 2 characters that represent the minutes).

Comment: @Larme There are no strings, just to `NSDate`. The OP just wants to ignore the "seconds" of the two `NSDate` instances.

Comment: On one hand, I'd like to close this question since it's essentially a duplicate of [Comparing two NSDate and ignoring the time component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854890/comparing-two-nsdates-and-ignoring-the-time-component?rq=1). On the other hand, it might not be obvious to a newbie how to modify those answers to solve the problem of the current question.

Comment: @rmaddy: That's where the description of the question is tricky. The author uses `NSDate` terms, and a format too. Which is quite confusing, and since `NSDate` object `description` method show the +0000, that's why I made the assumption of `NSString`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, probably the best way is to use [`-[NSCalendar isDate:equalToDate:toUnitGranularity:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDate:equalToDate:toUnitGranularity:).

```
BOOL datesAreEqual = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDate:date1
    equalToDate:date2 toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitMinute];
```

To compare them (find out which one is more recent/late), use [`-[NSCalendar compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:) instead.

Comment: I forgot about this one. So much better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`NSCalendar` has a very handy method to compare dates constrained to a particular unit. Set the `toUnitGranularity` parameter to `NSCalendarUnitMinute` and the seconds are ignored.

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:30.0];
NSComparisonResult compareDateIgnoringSeconds = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]        
                                                compareDate:date1 
                                                     toDate:date2 
                                          toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitMinute];
NSLog(@"%@, %@, %ld", date1, date2, compareDateIgnoringSeconds);
```

The result is `NSOrderedSame` for equality, `NSOrderedAscending` and `NSOrderedDescending` for `date1` before `date2` and `date1` after `date2`